# Mockito @Spy calls real method while mocking behaviour is defined

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test, springmockito

I have a common spring boot application consisting of a controller and a service layer. A database is not involved as I use another rest api to store the data.

Now I want to the my controller and therefor I want to mock my sevice partially. Partially because I have one method in it that takes a dto and converts it to my business model. I know this can also be solved with a constructor of the bussiness model but anyway I came to the following problem:

**CODE**

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class RegistrationController {

@Autowired
private UserRegistrationService userRegistrationService;

@PostMapping(value = "/user", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<UserId> createUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserDto userDto) {
    KeycloakUserRepresentation keycloakUserRepresentation = userRegistrationService.convertUserDtoToKeycloakUserRepresentation(userDto);
    UserId userId = userRegistrationService.createNewUser(keycloakUserRepresentation);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userId,HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

**TEST**

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ExtendWith({RestDocumentationExtension.class})
@AutoConfigureRestDocs
class RegistrationControllerRegistrationTest {

    private static final UserDto testUsertDto = new UserDto();

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Spy
    private UserRegistrationServiceImpl userRegistrationService;
```

In my test method I define:

```
doReturn(testUserId).when(userRegistrationService).createNewUser(any(KeycloakUserRepresentation.class));
```

**PROBLEM:**

I expect that while not define a doSomething in my test, the conversion of the userDto to a keycloak representation is done by the original method. This seems to work as when I debug in my Controller the keycloakUserRepresentation has the correct values. The problem is that in the next step the

> `createNewUser`

method is not stubbed/mocked. The original method is executed and so my test fails.
What I want is that when I provide a doSomething method in my testcase, I want the original method to be mocked.

Answer (score 1):

> This seems to work as when I debug in my Controller the
> keycloakUserRepresentation has the correct values.

It worked because the bean wasn't spied on at all. Although `@Spy` may help in creating a mocked object, it does not result in a mocked *Spring bean* in your test application context. Use [`@SpyBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html) to have Mockito spy on a bean in the Spring application context.